# number of quadratic residues modulo n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Define $f(n)$ to be the number of quadratic residues modulo $n$. I would like to show that $f$ is multiplicative, that is, for any positive integers $m,n > 1$, $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ whenever $(m,n) = 1$.

Let $S_n$ be the set of quadratic residues modulo $n$. Then my idea is to create a bijective map from $S_{mn}$ to $S_m \times S_n$.

Define the map $x \mod{mn} \mapsto (x \mod{m}, x \mod{n}$).

To show this is injective, suppose that two elements $x, x'$ from $S_{mn}$ map to the same ordered pair, that is $(x' \mod{m}, x' \mod{n}) = (x \mod{m}, x \mod{n})$. This implies both $m$ and $n$ divide $x - x'$. However, $(m,n) = 1$, so $mn$ divides $x - x'$.

To show this is surjective, we wish to show that for any ordered pair $(a \mod{m}, b \mod{n})$ there is an element $x$ in $S_{mn}$ that maps to it. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we have a unique solution to the system of congruences $x \equiv a \mod{m}$ and $x \equiv b \mod{n}$.

Here I am stuck. How do I show that $x$ must be an element of $S_{mn}$? I know I must continue using the Chinese Remainder Theorem but I am not seeing how to get the result I need.

Comment: Hint: you know that $a\equiv z_1^2\pmod m$ and $b\equiv z_2^2\pmod n$ for some integers $z_1,z_2$. Now what can you say about $z^2$, if $z\equiv z_1\pmod m$ and $z\equiv z_2\pmod n$.

Comment: I can say that $z^2 \equiv a \mod{m}$ and $z^2 \equiv b \mod{n}$ but that seems redundant to me.

Comment: Can you show that the residue class of $z^2\in S_{mn}$? (need to give missus a ride, back in half an hour or so :-)

Comment: Is it something like this?
I know I have a solution to $x \equiv a \mod{m}$ and $x \equiv b \mod{n}$ modulo $mn$. Since $z^2 \equiv a \mod{n}$ and $z^2 \equiv b \mod{n}$ By the chinese remainder theorem a solution is given by $x \equiv z^2 \mod{mn}$ so x is indeed an element of $S_{mn}$.

Comment: Something like that. But I think it is cleaner and clearer to ignore $x$, and start by saying that $a\equiv z_1^2\pmod m$ and $b\equiv z_2^2\pmod n$. Then do CRT to produce $z$ such that $z\equiv z_1\pmod m$, $z\equiv z_2\pmod n$, and then show that $z^2\bmod{mn}\mapsto (a\bmod m, b\bmod n)$.

Comment: it's bound by ceil(n/2) mod n at the highest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of quadractic residues $\mod p$ and $\mod n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764856/number-of-quadractic-residues-mod-p-and-mod-n)