# Question about equation in ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R=Z/pZ$ where $p$ is prime $>20$. Then the equation $x^2-a=0$ for $a\neq0$ can be solved in $R$:

1. $\forall a$ and $p$
2. only if $p\equiv1\bmod4$
3. for exactly $(p+1)/2$ $a$'s
4. for exactly $(p-1)/2$ $a$'s

Comment: 4.- that is, for half of the nonzero values of $a$ the equation is solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p>2$ be a prime (you do not need that $p>20$). Then among the integers $\{1,2,3,\cdots,p-1\}$ exactly half of them are quadratic residues modulo $p$. This just means that the equation $x^2-a=0$ has $(p-1)/2$ nonzero solutions. For more details see [Number of quadractic residues $\mod p$ and $\mod n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764856/number-of-quadractic-residues-mod-p-and-mod-n).